# Как отсортировать массив объектов по их свойствам?

Tags: javascript, alasql

```
var a = {prop: 3, name: 'a'},
    b = {prop: 2, name: 'b'},
    c = {prop: 1, name: 'c'};

var array = [ a, b, c ],
    result = null;

result = array.sort(function(a, b){
    var c = a.prop,
        d = b.prop;

    if( c < b ){
        return -1;
    }else if( c > b ){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

for(var i in result){
    console.log(result[i].name); // a, b, c
}
```

Так не работает...

**Добавлено:**
А в js так нельзя сортировать?? А какая разница сорту, что двигать местами?

Comment: Пару дней назад [похожий вопрос][1] был. Может, и вам пригодится.

   [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/360498/

Comment: @Deonis, Спасибо! У меня тоже самое, что и по Вашей ссылке, только с ошибкой:)  Но благодаря Вашей помощи я её смог увидеть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас две ошибки:

1. Метод sort сортирует массив на месте, т.е. изменяет массив, к которому он применен.
   Если вы хотите сохранить исходный массив, сделайте копию перед сортировкой:

   result = array.slice().sort()
2. Вы используете b в сравнениях `(c < b)` и `(c > b)`, хотя хотели d.

Исправленная программа работает как надо.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе многомерные сортировки решаются с помощью написания сложных функций для sort(), но это сложно, поэтому можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой, например, эта функция может быть реализована с помощью библиотеки [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql), которая предназначена для обработки массивов как в SQL.

```
var a = {prop: 3, name: 'a'},
    b = {prop: 2, name: 'b'},
    c = {prop: 1, name: 'c'};
var array = [ a, b, c ];

var result = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY name',[array]);
```

Порядок и количество полей можно варьировать с помощью ключевых слов ASC (по возрастанию)/DESC (по убыванию), например, так:

```
var result = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY name DESC, prop ASC',[array]);
```

Ваш пример [на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/ztc32a8h/5/).

Comment: @agershun, библиотека ваша интересная, но подключать 200 с лишним Кб ради сортировки - это как-то чересчур :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    var a = {prop: 3, name: 'a'},
    b = {prop: 2, name: 'b'},
    c = {prop: 1, name: 'c'},
    array = [ a, b, c ];

for (var i=0; 
         i < array.sort(function(obj1, obj2){
          return obj1.prop-obj2.prop;
          }).length;
         i++) {
    console.log(array[i].prop); 
}
```